# Is there a way to know if a number is included in another number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a simple program and I need to know if a number is part of a number entered by the user. Say for example that the user has picked the number 3, I need the program to perform an action when another number is 13, 23, 33, etc. If the user has picked the number 11 it needs to perform an action when the other number is 11, 21, 31, 41 and so on.

Comment: your second example isn't analogous to your first. Do you mean if the user picked the number `1`, or the number `11`?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine whether the difference between the number entered by the user and another number is a multiple of 10?

Comment: `bool(set(str(a)).intersection(str(b)))` or `any(i in str(b) for i in str(a))`.

Comment: @CoryKramer got it perfectly. If str(num1) in str(num2) solves my problem perfectly and very simply!

Comment: What does it mean for one number to be included in another number? Are you talking about the *textual representation* of a number being included in the *textual representation* of another number? (That's something *very* different from the number *itself* being included in another number!) And if that's what you mean, then what base is the textual representation in? Any base?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert both to `str` then check if the first is a substring of the other

```
def contains_num(a, b):
    return str(a) in str(b)
```

For example

```
>>> contains_num(3, 31)
True
>>> contains_num(3, 51)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an example of string parsing if you mean searching for the number in the second number (assuming 11 is a typo for 1)

```
def hasNumber(candidate, key):
  return str(candidate).find(str(key) >=0
```

But maybe you mean you want to know if the number contains the number + a multiple of 10.

```
def containsNumberPlusMultipleOfTen(candidate, key):
    return (candidate - key) % 10 == 0
```